# More efficient way to handle Mouseevent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, mouseevent

I have implemented a sankey chart, with the ability to trace a nodes path through the chart. However as the functionality stands, a user has to `mouseenter` a node to both highlight and remove the highlight of a node's path. What is a good way to highlight the node's path on mouseenter and then remove that highlight (via opacity change) `mouseout`? Btw I have tried to just call the function for using a combination of `mouseenter` and `mouseout` and that didn't seem to fix the problem. Here is my code:

```
function highlightNodeLinks(node, i) {

    var remainingNodes = [],
        nextNodes = [],
        strokeOpacity = 0,
        traverse;

    if ( d3.select(this).attr('data-hover') === '1' ) {
      d3.select(this).attr('data-hover', '0');
      strokeOpacity = 0.2;
    } else {
      d3.select(this).attr('data-hover', '1');
      strokeOpacity = 0.5;
    }

    traverse = [{
      linkType : 'sourceLinks',
      nodeType : 'target'
    }, {
      linkType : 'targetLinks',
      nodeType : 'source'
    }];

    traverse.forEach(function (step) {
      node[step.linkType].forEach(function (link) {
        remainingNodes.push(link[step.nodeType]);
        highlightLink(link.id, strokeOpacity);
      });

      while (remainingNodes.length) {
        nextNodes = [];
        remainingNodes.forEach(function (node) {
          node[step.linkType].forEach(function (link) {
            nextNodes.push(link[step.nodeType]);
            highlightLink(link.id, strokeOpacity);
          });
        });
        remainingNodes = nextNodes;
      }
    });
  }

  function highlightLink(id, opacity) {
    d3.select('#link-' + id).style('stroke-opacity', opacity);
  }
```

and here is how it is called:

```
  .on('mouseover', highlightNodeLinks)
```

As always thanks in advance for any consideration and advice.

Comment: How about pre-computing a list of all links in the path, then "just" iterating through this list to highlight them on or off? I can give some code if that's suitable for you (rather heavy memory load, but faster)

Comment: @tarulen I'd like to see your suggestion, if you wouldn't mind

Comment: can you give the nodes classes and set a :hover pseudo on the appropriate class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In two steps: first a preprocessing, so that each node "knows" the set of links that must be highlighted on mouseover. This is heavy for the memory (it won't scale for very large graphs), but should be much more responsive

```
//call this once after loading the data and first drawing of the links
node.forEach(function(n) {

 linkIds= []; //add this field to each node

 traverse.forEach(function (step) {
   node[step.linkType].forEach(function (link) {
     remainingNodes.push(link[step.nodeType]);
     linkIds.push(link.id);
   });

   while (remainingNodes.length) {
    nextNodes = [];
     remainingNodes.forEach(function (node) {
      node[step.linkType].forEach(function (link) {
         nextNodes.push(link[step.nodeType]);
         linkIds(link.id);
       });
     });
     remainingNodes = nextNodes;
   }

   //add the list of links to a new  field in the node
   //& transform already ids into d3 selections
   n.linksToHighlight = linkIds.map(function(id) {return d3.select("link-"+id)})
 });
```

Then, then highlighting code:

```
function highlighter(ratio) {
  return function(node) {
     node.linksToHighlight.forEach(function (s) {s.style("stroke-opacity",ratio})
  }
}


[select nodes]
 .on('mouseenter', highlighter(0.5) )     
 .on('mouseout', highlighter(1) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented a directive using d3 and i think you will find what you are looking for as example, you can check the code on github https://github.com/amgadfahmi/angular-bubbletree